# Salesforce Knowledge Article Field - Not Visible to Guest User

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am very new to Salesforce, so apologies if my use of terms is not correct.

I am using Lightning Knowledge

I have enable and setup Knowledge Base and added FAQ articles and have added Question and Answerr fields to those articles.

I have setup the field visibilty so they are visible to all user including "Read Only" users (I could not find anything specific for Guests, should there be?)

So as far as I can tell the field permissions on the Question and Answer fields is correct.

I create articles and enter my values for my  "Question and Answer fields" but when I go to my public site to view the FAQ, I only see the content of the Title and URL Name fields. I do not see my Question and Answer Fields.

If I login and view the articles via the public site, I do see the Question and Answer values.

I would very much appricaite it if anyone could point me in the right direction for trying to figure this out. I have googled but cannot seem to find anything that talks about guest users and field visibilty that has helped me.

Many Thanks
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, guest user is still an user. There's hidden user account (which acts as "created by" when you make new Case for example) and Profile which you might have to edit. It doesn't show up on normal list of profiles (but for example the Id can be queried and once you know Id you could construct the url yourself).

If you're using an Experience Cloud (aka Community) go to your site's Builder and the links will be at the bottom.

[image]

If you're using Sites - it should be in Site's config.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Eyescream but that does not address my problem. I was probably not clear enough. I can get to my public site (as a Guest) user and I can search for articles that I added to the knowledge base. But as a guest user I am only seeing the Title and URL name fields. As admin 
I set created FAQ articles, and I added Question and Answer fields, that should both be publicly visible (as far as I can tell). But when I search for FAQ (as a guest) on the public site, I find the article but my Question and Answer fields are not displayed.

Comment: Looks like stack "ate" part of my answer, I was posting during the outage. Have you found the guest profile, the FAQ article and checked the field level security? Maybe there are checkboxes you need to tick. Can you post a screenshot or sample url (with your SF domain redacted), maybe the article is displayed in special way and you will need to modify some code (visualforce page?)

Comment: Hi eyescream, I have managed to get access to the guest profile and found where I had to go and set the fields to allow view access. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but did see the solution documented in the previous comments.

1. In your community navigate to [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlVJT.png)
2. Select General
3. Click link under Guest User Profile
4. Scroll down to Field-Level Security
5. Click View for Knowledge
6. Click Edit
7. Check the Read Access box for the fields which are not displaying
8. Click Save