# Salesforce - Visualforce Page - Publicy Visible

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created a visualforce page with a chatbot snippet but I cannot see where to make the page visible to guest users. When I try to go to the page as a guest user, I am told I need to log in. I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks
Derek

Comment: Have you tried same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/67882766/313628 ? Find the guest user profile and there will be a section for Visualforce Page Access

Comment: Hi again Eyescream, yes I have added it to the "Enabled Visualforce Page Access" (sorry should have said that in my posting) but I am still asked to login.

Comment: How do you access the page. myPublicSite.force.com/vfPageName ? Or you could even set the VF page as default for the site and then just myPublicSite.force.com?

Comment: Ah! Eyescream, you have come to the rescue again, thanks so much. I was using the dev URL (not sure where I picked that up from) when I went to Setup -> All Sites and used the URL from there and added my Chat_Bot page to the URL it is now accessible to Guest users. Now on to my next challenge. Thanks again for your help